# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, url-rewriting

I am using AWS elastic beanstalk and have configure my htaccess as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /searchPage.php?crs_category=$1
```

The htaccess file is located at the root of the website, hence domain.com/.htaccess

the problem I now have is that the entire site doesn't work. nothing wrong in aws, health is green, but any page I load on the website says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" essentially what this rewriterule does it takes searchPage.php?crs_category=business for example and turn it to domain.com/category/business/

but not even the index.php is loaded or can be loaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. this how Allowoverwide all was enabled in aws (using ebextensions, I created a config file):

```
files:          
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf": 
     mode: "644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       AllowOverride All
```

but I don't think this where the error lies

Comment: "Connection Refused" almost certainly means the web server process isn't running at all.

Comment: but how is not running. thats the issue i am trying to resolve?

Comment: the instance is being run on php, when using htaccess in aws that shouldn't be a concern right?

Comment: I am suggesting that your problem may be entirely unrelated to this attempt at rewrite, and you need to check the web server's error logs the see what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, couldn't it be due to the change in permission?

Comment: What "change in permission" are you referring to?  Read your logs.